# What is the recommended number of accounts in an Organizational Unit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

We have no more than 50 Accounts in each of our Organizational Units, because two years ago someone from AWS recommended that. Unfortunately we need not clarify why and are now stuck with this magic number. Is 50 just a nice value for working in the AWS Console, or are there technical downsides to going over that number?